# Symmetry in $x=y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

What are the properties of a function being symmetrical in $x=y$ ? how would one find the image of a function reflected in $x=y$ ? and what would one need to prove to show that two functions are symmetrical(images of one another) in $x=y$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: the first implication that I can think of is that the functional inverse would be equal to the function.

Comment: Why is this? How would one go about proving it?

Comment: A functional inverse is just a reflection on the line x=y anyway (see this image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Inverse_Function_Graph.png). Therefore, if a function was already symmetrical, the above is true.

Answer (score 1):

Interchanging $x$ and $y$ yields the same expression.

Answer (score 0):

If a function's graph is symmetric with respect to the line $y = x$, then a point $(a, b)$ is on the graph if and only if the point $(b, a)$ is on the graph.

Example.  $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$

[image: reciprocal_function]

To find the image of a function reflected in the line $y = x$, interchange the values of $x$ and $y$.

Example.  The image of the graph of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is the graph of the function $g(x) = x^2, x \geq 0$.

[image: square_root_function_and_its_inverse]

To prove the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are symmetric with respect to the line $y = x$, show that $(a, b)$ is on the graph of $f(x)$ if and only if $(b, a)$ is on the graph of $g(x)$.  Note that this implies that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverse functions.

Example.  If $(a, b)$ lies on the graph of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, then $a = b^2$, so
$(b, a)$ lies on the graph of $g(x) = x^2, x \geq 0$.  If $(c, d)$ lies on the graph of $g(x)$, then $d = c^2$, with $c > 0$.  Hence, $(d, c)$ lies on the graph of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.